# HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: google-checkout, basic-authentication

http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70647

> Only accept messages that are
>   authenticated by HTTP Basic
>   Authentication, using your Merchant ID
>   and Merchant Key as the username and
>   password.

Any idea on how to set this up ? (HTTP Basic Authentication)

Answer (score 1):

In apache you set this up using a .htaccess & .htpass files. This website will generate the files for you: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

In IIS there is some setting under 'Directory Security' (I think) but I can't remember exactly how it works.

As for your specific google checkout problem... I'm not sure exactly what you mean, you havent provided much information...

Comment: I need AuthType Basic and AuthUserFile to work for a particular link - not the entire  directory